# High Level Assembler - Add record to File

Tags: assembly, macros

Hi I have an assembler program which opens a sequential file (doesn't read any records) but I'd like to add a record to the end.

I use the following statements;

```
`OPEN  (INPUT1,OUTPUT)
         TM    INPUT1+48,X'10
         BO    OPEN001        
         LH    R10,=H'2008'   
         B     ABENDRTN   

         PUT   INPUT1,INREC   

INPUT1  DCB   DDNAME=INPUT1,                                            
               DSORG=PS,                                                
               RECFM=FB,                                               
               MACRF=PM,                                              
               EODAD=INPUT002`
```

Problem is the above obliterates records already in the file when I just want to add a record at the end. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You should specify which architecture and assembler you're targeting.

Comment: I'm on z/OS using High Level Assembler

Comment: Meant to add the file is open as "Output" - if I open for update I get a S013-24. Reckon I must need correct combination of Open/MACRF

Comment: Answered own question, open for output, put as normal but JCL Disp=MOD. Should have known better!